# How to convert a SQL Result into JSON?

Tags: sql, json, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a simple way to convert a TSQL result into JSON? What I mean is, I input arbitrary SQL and it will return me JSON of the result set. Note I need to do this in TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SqlCommand Sc = new SqlCommand("Sp_Visa_SelectBy_id", new Conn().Con) {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        Sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        SqlDataReader Sdr = Sc.ExecuteReader();
        Visa Visa = new Visa();
        while (Sdr.Read())
        {
            Visa.id = Sdr.GetInt32(0);
            Visa.Name = Sdr.GetString(1);
            Visa.Desc = Sdr.GetString(2);
            Visa.Date = Sdr[3].ToString();
            Visa.Agency_id = Sdr.GetInt32(4);
        }
JavaScriptSerializer Js = new  JavaScriptSerializer();

       Js.Serialize(Visa);
```

Comment: what is the differnece , u have to Serialize YOUR CLASS to Json, after Fetching your data to ur class, you Have to USE
JavaScriptSerializer Js = new  JavaScriptSerializer();
Js.Serialize(Visa);

Comment: Check This One
http://technology.amis.nl/2011/06/14/creating-json-document-straight-from-sql-query-using-listagg-and-with-clause/

Comment: And This One 
http://firozansari.com/2008/11/21/generating-json-from-tsql-query/
Hope to be Usefull

Answer (score 0):

For sql result convert to JSON, need to use Serialize for JSON. Look at below:

```
Dataset DS = GETDATA(); //Get dataset and fill it from sql - table like name and address.

var var1 = from Res1 in DS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()

  select new
            {
            objName = Res1.Field<string>("Name"), 
            objAddress = Res1.Field<string>("Address"),
            };

JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string JsonResult = json.Serialize(var1).ToString();
```

-- here, in above code example, JsonResult is a string in which store string of json serialize your data. You can use this serialize data using $.parseJSON(msg.d.var1) in jQuery.